# Swift Package Manager: unable to dynamically link a target dependency within the same package

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I have an executable product and a dynamic library product in a SPM (Swift Package Manager) project:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "SomePackage",
    platforms: [.macOS(.v10_13)],
    products: [
        .executable(name: "executable", targets: ["executable"]),
        .library(name: "DynamicLibrary", type: .dynamic, targets: ["DynamicLibrary"])
    ],
    dependencies: [],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "executable",
            dependencies: ["DynamicLibrary"],
        ),
        .target(
            name: "DynamicLibrary",
            dependencies: [],
        ),
    ],
)
```

And the `DynamicLibrary` target is always statically linked into `executable`, despite the `dynamic` type set on the product.

It seems to be because that the `dynamic` type is set on the *product*, but not the *target*, and `executable` denpends on the *target* `DynamicLibrary` but not the *product* `DynamicLibrary`.

**Tried:**

1. Add a suffix "P" to product names so they differ from targets, then depend on the *product* `DynamicLibraryP` in `target.dependencies` of target `executable`: product 'DynamicLibraryP' is declared in the same package 'SomePackage' and can't be used as a dependency for target 'executable'.
2. Add the package itself to package.dependencies: circular depencency is not allowed.
3. Separate into two packages: I don't want this unless there are no other means.
4. Using custom linker flags including `-Xlinker -undefined -Xlinker dynamic_lookup` when calling `swift build`: does not help as well.
5. Switch to "the X thing" (not mentioning its name to avoid incorrect search results): impossible on Linux.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution? @Meow Cat 2012;
moving this dynamic library out to a separate spm is a potential solution

Comment: Yes, we did so...